# python text rpg inventory system

Tags: python

I'm making a text-based rpg with python 3.3 and I am wanting a more dynamic inventory system for my game. I am currently using variables assigned to each item but with functions, the variables I am passing as arguments are becoming too many and quite cluttered. If there is a better way out there I would love help creating a better system.

Here is how my inventory call system looks right now:

```
print('Item1',item1)
print('Item2',item2)
print('Item3',item3)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have an old text game I made and the inventory system I use is just a list named 'inv'. Then all you have to do when you gain an item of whatever type is to append the inventory list with the string.

```
inv = []

inv.append('Item1')
```

Then you can create a dictionary with the key as the item name and the value be a list you can reference. Try this:

```
itemvalues = {'Item1':[0,0,0]
}
```

And the list can be a bunch of different attributes such as buy sell price, strength or what have you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use a list:

```
inventory = []
inventory.append(some_item)
```

And you can implement an inventory cap:

```
if len(inventory) > inventory_size:
    print('Inventory full.')
```

If you want to 'use' an item in the inventory, say, then it's also easy to remove (this is of course assuming the index exists):

```
# use the item
del inventory[index]
```

Obviously most of the functionality you need is accessible through standard list methods, so check [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) out.